# How to combine two different mysql where clauses each results in 5 rows

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, union, where-clause

I use following two queries to obtain 5 rows from each and display in one list. Is there a possible way of combining two queries, so that I do not have to run them seperatly. But still get the same results, as results from the first where clause first and results from the second where caluse later.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
    institutes
    LEFT JOIN city ON institutes.city_id = city.city_id 
    LEFT JOIN district ON city.district_id = district.district_id 
    WHERE
    city.city_id = $current_city_id ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 5


    SELECT *
    FROM
    institutes
    LEFT JOIN city ON institutes.city_id = city.city_id 
    LEFT JOIN district ON city.district_id = district.district_id 
    WHERE
    district.district_id = $current_district_id ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: why you need 2query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried @Bohemian's answer, but it did not work for me. Thanks to his simple explanation, and by following this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) I was able to come up with below code that worked for me. But I do not know if there is a way that I can get rid of the redundancy associated with left joins in the code

```
sql = '(
  SELECT *
  FROM institutes
  LEFT JOIN city ON institutes.city_id = city.city_id 
  LEFT JOIN district ON city.district_id = district.district_id 
  WHERE city.city_id = $current_city_id
  )
  UNION
  (
  SELECT *
  FROM institutes
  LEFT JOIN city ON institutes.city_id = city.city_id 
  LEFT JOIN district ON city.district_id = district.district_id 
  WHERE district.district_id = $current_district_id
)
ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 10'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL` with wrapper `SELECT`s:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM institutes
    LEFT JOIN city ON institutes.city_id = city.city_id 
    LEFT JOIN district ON city.district_id = district.district_id 
    WHERE city.city_id = $current_city_id
    ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 5
) x1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM institutes
    LEFT JOIN city ON institutes.city_id = city.city_id 
    LEFT JOIN district ON city.district_id = district.district_id 
    WHERE district.district_id = $current_district_id
    ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 5 
) x2
```

The wrapper `SELECT`s are needed because you can't combine `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` and `UNION` at the same level, but you *can* put `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` in a *subquery*.

`UNION ALL` is needed rather than just `UNION` because `UNION` removes duplicates and your question requires duplicates to be kept.

`UNION ALL` also faster than `UNION` (because it doesn't have to de-dupe, which typically requires sorting), but in this case there's so few rows that the difference in performance wouldn't be noticed, but it's good to keep this in mind for future applications.

Comment: Note that there's a redundant LEFT JOIN in each subquery